# Access a local variable from a function on the global scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I have function a JSON/API loading callback function, where my `var json = JSON.parse(response);` is located that I use to read the JSON data:

```
// Call JSON File
function loadJSON(callback) {
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'pmApp.json', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
        // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
        callback(xobj.responseText);
    }
};
xobj.send(null);
};

// Run loadJSON - 
loadJSON(function (response) {
    // Parse JSON string into object
    var json = JSON.parse(response);
});
```

The `var json` is a local variable, and I would like to keep it that way (I don't want to make it global which would fix my issue), but I have a few functions that are called via HTML `onChange` events or on the global scope that need the `json` var to function correctly example:

```
//Global Scope
popBrandFields()

function popBrandFields(){
    var brand_items = json.brands[0][client];
};
```

I cant cal `popBrandFields(json)` because the `var json` is not accessible due to being on a local scope. (I want to keep it this way due to security, puting it on the global scope fixes my issue but I want to keep it in the local scope.)

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I was thinking of returning the `var json` from the function it is defined in but  I'm not sure how or if I can even set this type of function to a variable like in the following example:

```
function f(){
 var foo = 100;
return foo;
}

var a = f();
```

Maybe there is a better way to load the JSON that can achieve what Im looking for if anyone knows of one?

Comment: define the json variable at the global scope, then assign it's value in the AJAX call. The value will be captured in the global scope and made available to your other functions.

Comment: any specific reason why would you want json variable to be local and not global?

Comment: The fact that the data is loaded asynchronously means it is not a simple reference.

Comment: can you call `popBrandFields()` inside `loadJSON`?

Comment: you could still make it global and call the functions like popBranchFields after the json is loaded and for event handler functions, handle json being initialized or not in the event handler functions.

Comment: @AndrewLohr I have `onChange="popBrandFields()" ` events that are being fired when options in a dropdown are selected in the html so I cant move it it needs to stay global.

Answer (score 0):

You could ensure that all of the code that needs this value is in a SEF (self executing fuction).

It creates a scope inside the function where you can define all sorts of things, but does not pollute the global scope.

```
var globalVariable = 'bad'

(function(){
  var json = 'not a global variable';

  console.log('Your code goes here!');
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to create a function that held the rest of my code and vars, then I would call it from the `loadJSON` function passing in the `json` var so my new function can access it like so

```
loadJSON(function (response) {
    // Parse JSON string into object
    var json = JSON.parse(response);
    jsonUsingFunction(json);
});
```

This way none of my vars are on the global scope.

Also instead of using `onChange`from the HTML I used event listeners which fixed my issue!